# Create CW posts "Awarded at 10 rep"

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, community-wiki

On   the   privileges page, it's written that CW "posts" can be created by anyone with > 10 rep. Shouldn't it be changed to "answers"? . .  .

Comment: All the part of the detailed description *do* discuss only answers. Editing these pages seems to require more authority than a mere moderator, so I will migrate this to the mother meta.

Comment: @dmckee Actually, it requires less authority.

Comment: @dmckee Never mind, the title isn't 20k editable

Comment: Once upon a time, users could mark the question CW at the time of writing, guess that text hasn't really changed since the beginning. Agree it better be changed to prevent confusion.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - privilege wiki pages are CW posts as well as the Tag wikis.

Comment: @Oded so it's even more confusing since user with only 10 reputation can't create tag wiki and no user can create privilege wiki, just edit. (only its body)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Sure. Just splainin` where "posts" comes from

Comment: @Oded kk, fair enough.

Comment: @oded Unless I'm misunderstanding, the part that he wants to change is the title of the privilege ("Create Wiki Posts"). That's not editable by the community. The only thing we can change is [the description on that privilege's page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki), which appears to be correct.

Comment: @CodyGray - Frankly, I don't think that is editable. Period. I believe these come off directly from an enum.

Comment: @Oded That *doesn't* mean it's not editable, it means that you guys don't want to do the work to change the enum, or route that through a mechanism that allows for more flexibility.

Comment: @casperOne - talking about this point in time...

Comment: @Oded Hmm, I thought you guys had some internationalization changes coming soon. In which case, it ought to be easy to tweak the strings file. Also, by enum do you mean that there's an enum entry called `Privileges.CREATE_WIKI_POSTS` and the priv name is string manipulated from the enum entry? That's ... icky.

Comment: @Manishearth - The codebase has some dark corners (shipping code is sometimes more important than writing the "correct" code), and we do have some technical debt. Having said that, this is surely one of the things we are going to fix during i18n (which is, in fact, underway).

Comment: @Oded Ah, I see (I'd love to have a look at the code one day, it sounds like it's beautiful and horrible at the same time :P). I always thought that i18n was pretty much finished since SE was looking for a Portuguese-speaking comm team member. Oh well.

Comment: @Manishearth - We need to start _somewhere_...